# Depth buffer and alpha problems in XNA

Tags: .net, xna, xna-4.0, depth-buffer

I'm displaying many instances of `BasicEffect`, each of which is a 'plate' with one of four textures chosen at random, either partially transparent or fully opaque.

The problem I have is that when a plate with transparency is rendered, only the plates that are already rendered show through it.

It is hard to explain how everything is displayed so [here is the image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10530011/web-nie-usuwac/stackoverflow-smc-depth/img.png).

Is there a solution simpler than rendering in the right order for it?

Comment: Many instances of `BasicEffect`? You might be able to re-use a single instance.

Comment: @Andrew I'm planning to dynamically generate terrain so if I'm thinking right, I would have to update whole VertexBuffer if one verticle would change. For geometry presented in screenshot it would be ok, but for my case probably not. Please tell me if I'm missing something, I'm new to XNA.

Comment: The effect and vertex buffer are independent. You can have multiple buffers and use a single instance of the effect. If you will be frequently modifying the vertex buffer, consider a `DynamicVertexBuffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The depth buffer stores the "depth" of the topmost pixel that was drawn at that location. When you try to draw another pixel at that location, if it has a depth value **above** the value currently in the buffer, it will get drawn to the colour buffer and its depth value will replace the value in the depth buffer. But if another pixel comes along with a depth value **below** what is in the buffer - it is not drawn and the value in the depth buffer stays the same.

The upshot of this is that **the depth buffer does not work as expected with transparent pixels**. A transparent pixel may only result in a partial change of the colour buffer - but it completely replaces the value in the depth buffer. There is no way to draw "under" it.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

You could use **alpha testing**, which causes transparent pixels not to be rendered at all (and not change the depth buffer). This allows geometry to show through the transparent areas, independent of draw-order. The downside is that this does not work well with anti-aliasing (there is a good discussion of the anti-aliasing options [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/05/06/antialiasing-alpha-cutouts.aspx)).

Or you could **sort your geometry in back-to-front order**. You only have to sort your transparent geometry, if you draw your opaque geometry first.

Comment: Thank you for your throughoutful explanation, now everything is clear to me.  Thanks a lot :)